# Hide one item in DropDownList when DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1" in C# Asp.Net Web Forms

Tags: drop-down-menu

How can I hide one item in DropDownList when `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`?

I tried to do it:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Remove(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("Value"));
```

And this too:

```
DropDownList1.Items[/*index*/].Enabled = false;
```

But they do not work.

Comment: what is this? it doesn't look like javascript which is what I normally think of when it comes to dropdowns

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write: C# Asp.Net Web Forms